# 4g heap memory for dex operation is required?

Tags: android, android-studio, heap-memory

Is 4 gig heap memory required for dex operation ?? application not working on less heap memory device ,so how can i solve this issue??

In my app i used 4 gig heap memory but when i used app in low memory device its crashed and got Out Of Memory exception.so how can i managed?

if I set 1G memory for heap memory, permgen memory will be 512M, just example. If so, permgen will be 50% of heap memory. Could you provide the way for memory allocatation for them?

also i want to reduce heap memory and also want to use dex operation..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880346/how-to-allocate-heap-and-permgen-memory-for-4g-normally